# Best way to make my HoloLens 2 app run on smartphones

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, smartphone, mrtk

currently I am working on a project designed for the Hololens 2 using MRTK.
Now I want to make this app run on a mobile device (more specifially, an Android Smartphone) like any other AR app. Eventually these two should be able to communicate with each other. What would be the best way to go about it? The following ideas crossed my mind:

1. Copying and adapting the current scene made for Hololens by replacing Hololens exclusive features with ARCore features.
2. Creating a new project just for the mobile app.

Would love to hear your suggestions and ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MRTK supports a wide range of platforms, including mobile devices such as iOS and Android. You can use the MRTK API directly on your Android device instead of ARcore. For how to configure MRTK for iOS and Android please refer to this link:[Configure MRTK for iOS and Android [Experimental]](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/CrossPlatform/UsingARFoundation.html?)

Comment: I already found that guide, but ended up with a non-AR app in the end. Gonna try again, but I'm stuck since I can't find the option "UnityAR" in step 3: Mixed Reality Toolkit > Utilities > UnityAR > Update Scripting Defines

Comment: Update: I managed to get the app running, so the next question is, how would one handle Hololens exclusive features such as the hand menu? Probably would have to include another way to open it such as a button

Comment: You should design different UX interaction experiences for AR platforms with different interaction models. And in this case, it is best practice to place a touch button UI on the screen to replace the hand menu, instead of calling up the hand menu on the mobile platform.